# CMD Regular expression

Tags: windows, command-line

I am trying to create a command line (or .bat file) with a regular expression which has to replace * (multiple space characters) with  (single space character). Replace multiple space characters with only a single space character. In Unix we can use sed. However in our case this is not possible and installing sed is not an option.
Any ideas?

Comment: Must it be command line? What about calling a simple program/script?

Comment: Sure, this is possible as well.

Comment: What scripting languages do you have available (python, perl, etc)? I think that for this calling a script/program will be much cleaner than writing a bat script, but if you only need a hack then npocmaka's answer is probably good enough for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
set file_name_with_spaces="_ file    name   _.txt"

rem --- '?' is forbidden in file names ---
set file_name_with_no_spaces=%file_name_with_spaces: =?%
echo %file_name_with_no_spaces%

rem --- we need to to replace the quewstion marks that have primer numbers count and their modulus --
set file_name_with_no_spaces=%file_name_with_no_spaces:??=?%
set file_name_with_no_spaces=%file_name_with_no_spaces:???=?%
set file_name_with_no_spaces=%file_name_with_no_spaces:?????=?%
set file_name_with_no_spaces=%file_name_with_no_spaces:???????=?%
set file_name_with_no_spaces=%file_name_with_no_spaces:????????????=?%
set file_name_with_no_spaces=%file_name_with_no_spaces:???????=?%
set file_name_with_no_spaces=%file_name_with_no_spaces:???????=?%
set file_name_with_no_spaces=%file_name_with_no_spaces:???=?%
set file_name_with_no_spaces=%file_name_with_no_spaces:??=?%

set file_name_with_single_spaces=%file_name_with_no_spaces:?= %
rem ---  ---

echo %file_name_with_single_spaces%
ren %file_name_with_spaces% %file_name_with_single_spaces%
```

this should work in the most cases.If you have files with reeeeeeally a lot of spaces you'll need to add more expressions with `?`  (the also could be inserted in for loop but this was easier :-) ).

Comment: Thank you very much! This is working however on filename not on file contents :) Is it possible to replace set file_name_with_spaces="_ file    name   _.txt" with a result of a type command (type file.txt) in order to replace the file contents?

Comment: You can replace the 
set file_name_with_spaces="..."

Comment: Seems it's not working properly when meeting a new line symbol.

Comment: with simple `type` it will be not possible.You'll need to process the file with `for /f` loop  - it's possible but will require a little bit more complicated script. I think there was a similar example on http://www.dostips.com/ .